# How can I make this code faster?? List<custom_class>().Find(lambda_expression)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, lambda

I need to match email sends with email bounces so I can find if they were delivered or not. The catch is, I have to limit the bounce to within 4 days of the send to eliminate matching the wrong send to the bounce. Send records are spread over a period of 30 days.

```
LinkedList<event_data> sent = GetMyHugeListOfSends(); //for example 1M+ records
List<event_data> bounced = GetMyListOfBounces(); //for example 150k records

bounced = bounced.OrderBy(o => o.event_date).ToList(); //this ensures the most accurate match of bounce to send (since we find the first match)

List<event_data> delivered = new List<event_data>();
event_data deliveredEmail = new event_data();

foreach (event_data sentEmail in sent)
{

     event_data bounce = bounced.Find(item => item.email.ToLower() == sentEmail.email.ToLower() && (item.event_date > sentEmail.event_date && item.event_date < sentEmail.event_date.AddDays(deliveredCalcDelayDays)));

     //create delivered records
     if (bounce != null)
     {
          //there was a bounce! don't add a delivered record!
     }
     else
     {
          //if sent is not bounced, it's delivered
          deliveredEmail.sid = siteid;
          deliveredEmail.mlid = mlid;
          deliveredEmail.mid = mid;
          deliveredEmail.email = sentEmail.email;
          deliveredEmail.event_date = sentEmail.event_date;
          deliveredEmail.event_status = "Delivered";
          deliveredEmail.event_type = "Delivered";
          deliveredEmail.id = sentEmail.id;
          deliveredEmail.number = sentEmail.number;
          deliveredEmail.laststoretransaction = sentEmail.laststoretransaction;

          delivered.Add(deliveredEmail);   //add the new delivered
          deliveredEmail = new event_data();

          //remove bounce, it only applies to one send!
          bounced.Remove(bounce);
     }

     if (bounced.Count() == 0)
     {
          break; //no more bounces to match!
     }
}
```

So I did some testing and it's processing about 12 sent records per second. At 1M+ records, it will take 25+ hours to process!

Two questions:

1. How can I find the exact line that is taking the most time?
2. I am assuming it's the lambda expression finding the bounce that is taking the longest since this was much faster before I put that in there. How can I speed this up?

Thanks!

**Edit**

---Ideas---

1. One idea I just had is to sort the sends by date like I did the bounces so that the search through the bounces will be more efficient, since an early send would be likely to hit an early bounce as well.
2. Another idea I just had is to run a couple of these processes in parallel, although I would hate to multi-thread this simple application.

Comment: Another performance thing, but not enough for an answer. instead of `item.email.ToLower() == sentEmail.email.ToLower()` do `item.email.Equals(sentEmail.email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` it keeps you from having to generate two new string every time to compare the two items.

Comment: Thanks scott, I will use that too. I need to eek out every last bit of performance that I can. :-)

Comment: @RichardDesLonde after reading your question, I wondering, why is the order of bounces relevant? All you are testing for is the presence of a bounce in a relative date range, you don't use data from the bounce so why the order?

Comment: Hi Jodrell. There could be multiple bounces within the 4 day range. The order just makes sure I get the first relevant bounce (which is what I want).

Comment: I was being dumb, I missed the remove, reworking my answer.

Comment: I reworked my answer to match your actual requirement, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16709825/659190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the final solution I found was a Dictionary for the bounces.

The sent LinkedList was sorted by sent_date so it would loop through in chronological order. That's important because I have to match the right send to the right bounce.

I made a `Dictionary<string,<List<event_data>>`, so the key was email, and the value was a List of all `<event_data>` bounces for the email address. The List was sorted by event_date since I wanted to make sure the first bounce was matched to the send.

**Final result...it went from processing 700 records/minute to 500k+ records/second.**

Here is the final code:

LinkedList sent = GetMyHugeListOfSends();
IEnumerable sentOrdered = sent.OrderBy(send => send.event_date);

Dictionary> bounced = GetMyListOfBouncesAsDictionary();

List delivered = new List();
event_data deliveredEmail = new event_data();

List bounces = null;
bool matchedBounce = false;

foreach (event_data sentEmail in sentOrdered)
{
     matchedBounce = false;

```
 //create delivered records
 if (bounced.TryGetValue(sentEmail.email, out bounces))
 {
      //there was a bounce! find out if it was within 4 days after the send!
      foreach (event_data bounce in bounces)
      {
           if (bounce.event_date > sentEmail.event_date &&
               bounce.event_date <= sentEmail.event_date.AddDays(4))
           {
               matchedBounce = true;

               //remove the record because a bounce can only match once back to a send
               bounces.Remove(bounce);

               if(bounces.Count == 0) //no more bounces for this email
               {
                    bounced.Remove(sentEmail.email);
               }

               break;
          }
     }

     if (matchedBounce == false) //no matching bounces in the list!
     {
          //if sent is not bounced, it's delivered
          deliveredEmail.sid = siteid;
          deliveredEmail.mlid = mlid;
          deliveredEmail.mid = mid;
          deliveredEmail.email = sentEmail.email;
          deliveredEmail.event_date = sentEmail.event_date;
          deliveredEmail.event_status = "Delivered";
          deliveredEmail.event_type = "Delivered";
          deliveredEmail.id = sentEmail.id;
          deliveredEmail.number = sentEmail.number;
          deliveredEmail.laststoretransaction = sentEmail.laststoretransaction;

          delivered.Add(deliveredEmail);   //add the new delivered
          deliveredEmail = new event_data();
     }
 }
 else
 {
      //if sent is not bounced, it's delivered
      deliveredEmail.sid = siteid;
      deliveredEmail.mlid = mlid;
      deliveredEmail.mid = mid;
      deliveredEmail.email = sentEmail.email;
      deliveredEmail.event_date = sentEmail.event_date;
      deliveredEmail.event_status = "Delivered";
      deliveredEmail.event_type = "Delivered";
      deliveredEmail.id = sentEmail.id;
      deliveredEmail.number = sentEmail.number;
      deliveredEmail.laststoretransaction = sentEmail.laststoretransaction;

      delivered.Add(deliveredEmail);   //add the new delivered
      deliveredEmail = new event_data();
 }

 if (bounced.Count() == 0)
 {
      break; //no more bounces to match!
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would be reasonably confident in saying that yes it is your find that is taking the time.

It looks like you are certain that the find method will return 0 or 1 records only (not a list) in which case the way to speed this up would be to create a lookup (a dictionary) instead of creating a `List<event_data>` for your bounced var, create a `Dictionary<key, event_data>` instead, then you can just look-up the value by key instead of doing a find.

The trick is in creating your key (I don't know enough about your app to help with that) but essentially the same criteria that is in your find.

EDIT. (adding some pseudo code)

```
void Main()
{
    var hugeListOfEmails = GetHugeListOfEmails();
    var allBouncedEmails = GetAllBouncedEmails();
    IDictionary<string, EmailInfo> CreateLookupOfBouncedEmails = CreateLookupOfBouncedEmails(allBouncedEmails);

    foreach(var info in hugeListOfEmails)
    {
        if(CreateLookupOfBouncedEmails.ContainsKey(info.emailAddress))
        {
            // Email is bounced;
        }
        else
        {
            // Email is not bounced
        }
    }

}

public IEnumerable<EmailInfo> GetHugeListOfEmails()
{
    yield break;
}

public IEnumerable<EmailInfo> GetAllBouncedEmails()
{
    yield break;
}

public IDictionary<string, EmailInfo> CreateLookupOfBouncedEmails(IEnumerable<EmailInfo> emailList)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, EmailInfo>();
    foreach(var e in emailList)
    {
        if(!result.ContainsKey(e.emailAddress))
        {
            if(//satisfies the date conditions)
            {
                result.Add(e.emailAddress, e);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public class EmailInfo
{
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim - It has to find a matching email address, and the first bounce within 4 days of the send...how would I create a key like that? Email address and bounce date?

Comment: Actually looking more closely at your code, the key would simply be the email address. just filter by your criteria in the construction of the dictionary.

Comment: When you create the dictionary, use the overload that [lets you pass in the comparator to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx), and pass in [StringComparer.OrdnalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx). If you do that you don't need to worry about passing in `ToLower()` everywhere.

Comment: So the problem is that the email is not unique...there could be multiple bounce records for the same email address...each with a different bounce date.

Comment: Same with sends...there could be multiple sends for the same email address with different send dates.

Comment: Tim, what do you think about using a tuple for this?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a Tuple with the email address and the date. However if it were me, I'd just populate the dictionary with the bounced emails within the date range that you want to test for so that the email address is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You should improve by using `ToLookup` method to create lookup table for email address

```
var bouncedLookup = bounced.ToLookup(k => k.email.ToLower());
```

and use this in the loop to lookup by the email first

```
var filteredBounced = bouncedLookup[sent_email.email.ToLower()];
// mini optimisation here
var endDate = sentEmail.event_date.AddDays(deliveredCalcDelayDays);
event_data bounce = filteredBounced.Find(item => item.event_date > sentEmail.event_date && item.event_date < endDate));
```

I could not compile it but I think that should do. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks! I will consider that suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Converting bounced to sortedlist might be a good solution

```
SortedList<string,data> sl = new SortedList<string,event_data>(bounced.ToDictionary(s=>s.email,s=>s));
and to find a bounce use
sl.Select(c=>c.Key.Equals(item => item.email,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && ...).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding items in a list. That means it has to traverse the whole list so it is an order (n) operation. Could you not store those sent emails in a Dictionary with the key being the email address you are searching on. The go through the bounces linking back to the emails in the dictionary. The lookup will be constant time and the you will go through the bounces so it will be order (n) overall. You current method is order (n squared)

Comment: So you are recommending making the sent data a dictionary, and looping through the bounces to find the correlating send for each bounce?

Answer (score 0):

On Consideration, the number of bounces is relatively small, so,

Why not pre omptimise the bounce lookup as much as possible, this code makes a delegate for each possible bounce and groups them into a dictionary for access by the e-mail key.

```
private static DateInRange(
    DateTime sendDate,
    DateTime bouncedDate,
    int deliveredCalcDelayDays)
{
    if (sentDate < bouncedDate)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return sentDate < bouncedDate.AddDays(deliveredCalcDelayDays);
}

static IEnumerable<event_data> GetDeliveredMails(
           IEnumerable<event_data> sent,
           IEnumerable<event_data> bounced,
           int siteId,
           int mlId,
           int mId,
           int deliveredCalcDelayDays)
{
    var grouped = bounced.GroupBy(
        b => b.email.ToLowerInvariant());

    var lookup = grouped.ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.OrderBy(e => e.event_date).Select(
            e => new Func<DateTime, bool>(
                s => DateInRange(s, e.event_date, deliveredCalcDelayDays))).ToList());

    foreach (var s in sent)
    {
        var key = s.email.ToLowerInvariant();

        List<Func<DateTime, nool>> checks;
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(key, out checks))
        {
            var match = checks.FirstOrDefault(c => c(s.event_date));
            if (match != null)
            {
                checks.Remove(match);
                continue;
            }
        }

        yield return new event_data
            {
                .sid = siteid;
                .mlid = mlid;
                .mid = mid;
                .email = s.email;
                .event_date = s.event_date;
                .event_status = "Delivered";
                .event_type = "Delivered";
                .id = s.id;
                .number = s.number;
                .laststoretransaction = s.laststoretransaction
            };
    }

}
```

You could try pre-compiling the delegates in lookup if this is not fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's another concern about your code, that I want to point out.

Memory consumption. I don't know your machine configuration, but here are some thoughts about the code:

1. Initially you are allocating space for 1,2M+ objects of `event_data`
   type. I can't see `event_data` full type definition, but assuming
   that emails are all unique and seeing that the type has quite many
   properties, I can assume that such a collection is rather *heavy*
   (hundreds of Meg possibly).
2. Next you are allocating another bunch of `event_data` objects
   (almost 1M if I've counted it right). It's getting even *more heavy*
   in terms of memory consumption
3. I don't know about other objects, that are present in data-model of your application, but considering all things I've mentioned, you can easily get close to memory limit
   for 32-bit process and thus force GC to work **very often**. In fact
   you can easily have a GC collecting after each call
   `bounced.Remove(bounce);` And it's really would **significantly** slow down your app.

So, even if you are having a plenty of memory left and/or your app is 64-bit, I would try to minimize memory consumption. Pretty sure it would get your code run faster. For example, you can do complete processing of `deliveredEmail`, without storing it, or load your initial `event_data` in chunks etc.

Comment: Hi Koka, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I don't have any other way to do it (that I can think of). I get the data from an API call and have to keep it in memory in order to calculate the delivered data.